# Is it possible to define the mean of a varying distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, dirichlet-distribution, nonparametric-bayes

Suppose $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ be the vector of multinomial parameters and $$(p_1,\ldots,p_k)\sim \mbox{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k).$$
Let's define a function $f(p_1,\ldots,p_k) \in \mathbb{R}$. After collecting some observations $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ incrementally  we have $$(p'_1,\ldots,p'_k)\Big|(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\sim \mbox{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1+x_1,\ldots,\alpha_k+x_k).$$
Imagine we calculate $f$ after each increment to the $x_i$'s. Can we calculate the mean over the outputs of $f$? Or, can we say anything about the changes between $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ and $(p'_1,\ldots,p'_k)$?

Answer (score 2):

The mean of $f(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ is defined in terms of the distribution of $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$, namely $$(p_1,\ldots,p_k)\sim \mbox{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1+n_1,\ldots,\alpha_k+n_k).$$Hence, if the data $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ changes, so does the distribution of $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$, and the means 
$$\int f(p_1,\ldots,p_k) \pi((p_1,\ldots,p_k)|(n_1,\ldots,n_k))\,\text{d}\mathbf{p}$$
differ. Averaging successive means as $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ grows does not make sense from either a probabilistic (this is no longer a mean against a fixed distribution) or from a Bayesian (the final posterior distribution contains all the relevant information) viewpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can we say anything about the changes  between $(p_1,\ldots,p_k)$ and $(p'_1,\ldots,p'_k)$? In other words, can we say if we increase $\alpha_i$ by $n_i$ in the sampled multinomial vector the values would change by $\delta$ before actually sampling $p'_i$s?